# BiWeekly Iterating over daylight savings change

Tags: java, icalendar, biweekly

I am trying to iterate an event across a daylight savings change with the Java BiWeekly library.

Say the event starts at 8am, I want it to stay at 8am regardless of whether daylight savings is in effect or not.

The following code is from the BiWeekly website: https://github.com/mangstadt/biweekly/wiki/Examples#calculating-the-dates-in-a-recurring-event

```
ICalendar ical = ...
TimezoneInfo tzinfo = ical.getTimezoneInfo();

VEvent event = ical.getEvents().get(0);
DateStart dtstart = event.getDateStart();

TimeZone timezone;
if (tzinfo.isFloating(dtstart)){
  timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
} else {
  TimezoneAssignment dtstartTimezone = tzinfo.getTimezone(dtstart);
  timezone = (dtstartTimezone == null) ? TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC") : dtstartTimezone.getTimeZone();
}
DateIterator it = event.getDateIterator(timezone);
```

If I have a celendar created as:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Michael Angstadt//biweekly 0.6.3//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:deb01413-942a-4ea9-a53c-541493fa668a
DTSTAMP:20200213T051827Z
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Team Meeting
DTSTART;TZID=/Pacific/Auckland:20200213T181827
DURATION:PT1H
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Iterating over this, the time changes by an hour as it crosses the daylight savings boundary.

How should it be done to keep the occurrences occurring at the given time? (It is correct that it occurs at the same time in UTC, but I want it to occur at the same time locally.)

Comment: What timezone are you in?  With Java you can get the EPOCH time since 1970 in milliseconds, this is already in UTC, you then just need to offset for your timezone.

Comment: Don't believe it, looks like it is a timezone issue, the problem was with the code above the iterator was getting the UTC timezone if the dtstartTimezone was null. Forcing the correct timezone worked. I still need to do a bit more testing as to why it did not pick up the Pacific/Auckland timezone that (I believe) is in the calendar. Once that is figured I will post back an answer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hey, this is the creator of biweekly. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue myself, but if you continue to have trouble, please don't hesitate to open an issue on the project's GitHub page: https://github.com/mangstadt/biweekly/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the `dtstartTimezone` in the code above is returning null even though there was a timezone in the `DTSTART` of the event. (That might be another issue to track down.)

Because this was null the iterator was getting a UTC timezone and hence the dates iterated were UTC based and changed when crossing the daylight saving boundary in the target timezone.

Removing the timezone assignment code that pulled the timezone out of the calendar and replacing it with `val timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland")` (or the proper timezone) and using that in the iterator fixes this issue.